# unsigned char to char * for TCP from C++ WinSock client to C# Server

Tags: c#, c++, tcp, winsock2, tcplistener

I'm having trouble with a problem, that I think is just a case of casting from unsigned char to char*.  However, I've not managed to do it in a way that works!

What I'm doing is reading data in to a C++ program as an unsigned char [64].  This then needs to be transmitted over a TCP socket to a waiting C# TcpListener (I've also tried listening with [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) on linux, and [Hurcules](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html).

The listener (whichever one I use) receives nothing that makes sense!
If I `char* buffer2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);` I get something transmitted, but it's nonsense, and when I inspect buffer2 during debug it contains only a "0".

Below is some stripped back C++ code for sending using my own SocketClient_Winsock class (which is even further down)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SocketClient_Winsock.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void GetData(unsigned char *fillme)
{

    // Fill the array!
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
    {
        fillme[a] = a;
    }

    printf("in GetData: \n");
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", fillme[a]);
    printf("\n\n");


}


void SendData(char* sendme)
{
    printf("in SendData: \n");
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", sendme[a]);
    printf("\n\n");

    SocketClient_Winsock sock("127.0.0.1"); // Default constructor 127.0.0.1:5000
    sock.Start();
    //sock.Send("Incoming!\n");
    sock.Send(sendme);
    //sock.Send("Done.");
    sock.Stop();


}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Create the buffer
    unsigned char buffer[64];

    printf("Before filling: \n"); // output
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", buffer[a]);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Fill the buffer
    GetData(buffer);    

    printf("after filling: \n"); // output again
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", buffer[a]);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Send data over TCP connection    
    SendData((char*)buffer);

    // Output
    printf("after sending: \n");
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", buffer[a]);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the SocketClient_Winsock.h:

```
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "5000"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
using namespace std;
class SocketClient_Winsock
{
private:

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    //char *sendbuf = "this is a test"; // we expect this to be sent back from the class
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;


    char* serverName;

public:
    SocketClient_Winsock();
    SocketClient_Winsock(char* servername);
    bool Start();
    int Stop();
    int Send(string);
    int Send(char*);
    int Send(unsigned char*);
    bool Recv();

    ~SocketClient_Winsock();
};
```

And the SocketClient_Winsock.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SocketClient_Winsock.h"
#include <iostream>
// From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx
SocketClient_Winsock::SocketClient_Winsock()
{
    serverName = "127.0.0.1"; // Default to localhost
}
SocketClient_Winsock::SocketClient_Winsock(char * servername)
{
    serverName = servername;
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
bool SocketClient_Winsock::Start() {

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(serverName, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    return true;
};

int SocketClient_Winsock::Stop()
{
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
};

// Send message to server
int SocketClient_Winsock::Send(char* msg)
{

    printf("during sending: \n");
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        printf("%i, ", msg[a]);
    printf("\n\n");

    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, msg, (int)strlen(msg), 0);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
};



int SocketClient_Winsock::Send(std::string msg)
{

    int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        Stop();
        return false;
    }

    return 0;
};

// Receive message from server
bool SocketClient_Winsock::Recv()
{
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);

    if (iResult > 0)
    {

        std::string msg = std::string(recvbuf);

        msg.erase(msg.find_first_of("\n"), msg.length()); // remove all characters after /n
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
SocketClient_Winsock::~SocketClient_Winsock()
{
    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

And the C# Host:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace Receiver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // now listen:
            Int32 port = 5000;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[64];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop. 
            while(true) 
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
                while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
                {   
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);


                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);


                    // Send back a response.
                    //stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C++'s `char` is C#'s `byte` so `char*` roughly equals `byte*` or `byte[]` and by the way post some C# code.

Comment: The C# end is using byte[]... C# code posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MagikM18 commented below, the original solution was no solution at all... just a workaround to a bug.

The bug was in the C# side of things (which I ignored, thinking it was from the MSDN, it'll be fine.  Don't do that!).  It was taking my data and forcing it into ASCII - hence the nonsense.  If I looked at the raw data all was fine.

So, my Send Data now looks like this:

```
int SocketClient_Winsock::Send(char* msg, int msgLength)
{
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, msg, msgLength, 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

and is called by:
`sock.Send((char*)buffer, BUFFER_LEN);`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. You're sending binary data, so you shouldn't use the string class. The reality is that you have a bug in your code, and this is just a workaround instead of a fix. The bug is in `Send(char*)` function, where you clearly assume that the data is 64 bytes, but you use `strlen` to get the length for WinSock. This won't work because it assumes that the string is text, not binary, so it will complete at the first zero it finds, which is not the intention; instead, you should simply pass 64 again. A better solution would be to add a parameter for message length.

Comment: Spot on - and I sort of knew something wasn't right, but got to the point where I was getting what I wanted and posted it.  I've gone back and fixed it now with a more suitable solution.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just FYI, next time please don't update code in the question, as it could confuse people trying to answer or looking at other answers; instead, update your answer or add a new one.